# use cat to send input file to java main class

Tags: java, file-io, program-entry-point, cat

If i want to input file say myfile.txt using cat command

say "cat myfile.txt > java myMain"

What should I write in  myMain function ? Is myfile.txt stored directly in args[0] or is there a way to reference it ?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075069/core-java/the-ins-and-outs-of-standard-input-output.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't do it *quite* like that - that's currently redirecting to a file. You either want to *pipe* it to `java`, or redirect in the other way:

```
java Foo < myTextFile
```

or

```
cat myTextFile | java Foo
```

Next, you should use `System.in`, as you're basically using the contents of that file as standard input instead of the console:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in, Charset.defaultCharset()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Read: " + line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```